# N-Queen Problem: Cannot figure out why my solution is not working

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was having a go at the standard N-Queens problem for an upcoming interview.
I have tried to dry run my code and it seems to work fine. I can't spot the error in my code.

I am traversing it column by column, and using backtracking to recur back from an incorrect path.
Can anyone help me with why this doesn't give me the desired output (details below)?

Here's the [problem statement](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/n-queen-problem/0)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve(vector<vector<int>> &ans, vector<int> &curr, int col, int n){
    if(col==n){
        ans.push_back(curr);
        return;
    }
    bool flag=false;
    
    for(int row=0; row<n; row++){
        if(col==0){
            curr.push_back(row);
            solve(ans, curr, col+1, n);
            curr.pop_back();
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0; i<curr.size(); i++){
                if((curr[i] == row) || (abs(row-curr[i]) == (col-i))){
                    flag=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag)
                continue;
            curr.push_back(row);
            solve(ans, curr, col+1, n);
            curr.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

int main()
 {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        vector<int> curr;
        solve(ans, curr, 0, n);
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
            cout << "[";
            for (int j = 0; j < ans[i].size(); j++) 
                cout << ans[i][j]+1 << " "; 
            cout << "]";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sample input would look like:

```
2
1
4
```

and the corresponding output would be:

```
[1 ]
[2 4 1 3 ] [3 1 4 2 ]
```

The compiler gives me an output (for my code):

```
[1 ]
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "doesn't work"? What output do you get?

Comment: Doesn't give the correct output. Details updated.

Comment: @KaranSingh Non-related, but you should not [use using std;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and [include bits/stdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: @Kerek totally agree. I only use them for interview preparation. It saves time. I make it a point to explain it to the interviewer as well.

Comment: @KaranSingh you shouldn't anyway... Not all interviewers will see it as a positive, even if you know that it is wrong. Just include the appropriate code, and use `std::`

Comment: @KaranSingh doesn't meter, this way you are perpetuating bad habits. If you do this during interview you may lose some pints.

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  For example, the statement causing the issue, expected values of variables and actual values of variables.

Comment: @KaranSingh *I only use them for interview preparation* -- What if the interview is done using the Visual C++ compiler?  There is no such header as `bits/stdc++` there.  A good interviewer is one who will see if, within one or two, maybe three attempts, you know the correct headers to include.  If you're fumbling around not knowing that for example, `std::find_if` is in the `<algorithm>` header, that takes points away.

Comment: Why do you have twice the test `col == n` ? A typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bool flag` variable (used to check if placing a queen at `(row, col)` would intersect with any existing queens in `curr`) is currently being re-used across rows.

So, if you place the line `bool flag=false;` just above `for(int i=0; i<curr.size(); i++){`, it should produce the correct output for your test case.

Other notes:

1. It might be easier to create a separate function `bool does_intersect(const vector<int>& cur, int row, int col)` to check the queen intersection condition so that the `bool flag` variable isn't needed.
2. The `if(col==0){` condition can be removed since it doesn't do anything that the `else` part cannot already handle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple way to solve the problem of the N-Queens using backtracking:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int m[20][20];
bool ended = false;

void print(int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout<<(m[i][j] == -1? "O" : "-")<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void fill(int val, int row, int col, int n){
    int d = 1;
    for(int i = col + 1; i < n; i++, d++){
        m[row][i] += val;
        if(row - d >= 0) m[row - d][i] += val;
        if(row + d < n)  m[row + d][i] += val;
    }
}

void solve(int n, int col = 0){
    if(ended) return;        
    if(col == n){ print(n); ended = true; return; }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(m[i][col] == 0){
            m[i][col] = -1;
            fill(1, i, col, n);
            solve(n, col + 1);
            m[i][col] = 0;
            fill(-1, i, col, n);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    memset(m, 0, sizeof(m));
    solve(8);                 //dimension of board    
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to always look forward. Place a queen in a slot that is 0 in the matrix. After that, add 1 in all slots where she can move to. When you return from the backtracking, subtract 1 from the same slots you just added and continue trying.

Answer (score 0):

This solution passes LeetCode's online judge for N Queens problem, and uses three flags to solve the problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> solveNQueens(int n) {
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> possibilities;
        std::vector<std::string> n_queens(n, std::string(n, '.'));
        std::vector<int> flag_col(n, 1);
        std::vector<int> flag_diag_a(2 * n - 1, 1);
        std::vector<int> flag_diag_b(2 * n - 1, 1);
        solveNQueens(possibilities, n_queens, flag_col, flag_diag_a, flag_diag_b, 0, n);
        return possibilities;
    }

private:
    void solveNQueens(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& possibilities,
                      std::vector<std::string>& n_queens,
                      std::vector<int>& flag_col, std::vector<int>& flag_diag_a, std::vector<int>& flag_diag_b,
                      int row, int& n) {
        if (row == n) {
            possibilities.push_back(n_queens);
            return;
        }

        for (int col = 0; col != n; col++) {
            if (flag_col[col] && flag_diag_a[row + col] && flag_diag_b[n - 1 + col - row]) {
                flag_col[col] = flag_diag_a[row + col] = flag_diag_b[n - 1 + col - row] = 0;
                n_queens[row][col] = 'Q';
                solveNQueens(possibilities, n_queens, flag_col, flag_diag_a, flag_diag_b, row + 1, n);
                n_queens[row][col] = '.';
                flag_col[col] = flag_diag_a[row + col] = flag_diag_b[n - 1 + col - row] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

For interview, you should not probably use:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
```

and make sure to write clean codes.

---

N Queens is a low frequency interview question. There are much better questions to be asked in the interviews (such as [Number of Islands](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/)), probably you would not get N Queens. But, it's good to practice.